# Questions about instance variables and declaring their properties

Tags: iphone, xcode, properties, header

If I declare instance variables and objects in my header between brackets with "IBOutlet" in front of them, do I have to set the objects properties?

Also does this mean they are private? What does it mean for them to BE private???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,It is not necessary to set properties for IBOutlets, Just declaring them would be enough
for eg:

```
 IBOutlet UIbutton *btn;
```

If you want the variables to be private then you will have to declare it in this form

```
@interface myclass:NSObject
{
   @private
   int var1;
}
```

Instance variables declared as private in a class can be accessed only by an instance of the class.

Answer (score 1):

If you do `@property` and `@synthesize` you do not have to declare variables. The .h file is an api for a class so declaring anything inside it, has an intension to be public rather than private.

To declare IBOutlet private, you need to create a category,

```
@interface YourViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

@end
```

Above code will be inside .m file.

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

You just have to declare variables of an object as IBOutlets (assuming you are hooking them up using Interface Builder). They don't have to be properties unless you have a reason to make them a property (i.e. you want the variable to be accessible by other objects). A private property can't be accessed by an external object.